# .doc to html in PHP display no image

Tags: php, html, docx

I have `someimage.docx` that contains text and images. I used https://github.com/xylude/Docx-to-HTML to convert it to html but it seems the text were only shows and the images won't shows up.
does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: check the image url and check whether that path exists

Comment: I think the image were pasted/inserted in the .docx file

Comment: No, check the output hmtl for the image paths.

Comment: it shows only the text html such as `p`, `h1`, ..... but no `img` html tag for the images..

Comment: I just had a quick look at the source code of that library and I can't see anything that would suggest that is supports images. Actually considering how complex converting Word files to HTML would probably be, I can't imagine how a 200 line library could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

That library can't convert images in doc to html. I would suggest you to use any online services to do that. You can get their api too. [Cloudconvert](https://cloudconvert.com) is one of them

They have rest api too, check further details on https://cloudconvert.com/apiconsole

Comment: I only need the `.doc` file to be read as `html` not to download the `html`.. is it possible?

Comment: yes. They will give you the html file. Instead of downloading put it into a link. So clicking on that link you can read the html file from your browser itself